# How to disable SCSS property by overwriting it?

Tags: css, sass

How could I disable `background-color` in `.button.search` so it would fallback to `$red` value? I can't remove it; I can only overwrite it.

I have

```
.button {
background-color: {$red};
}
```

and

```
.button.search {
background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `backgroung-color: inherit;`?

Comment: is there a reason why you need to apply a `background-color` if you don't even want it in the first place?

Comment: You can add `!important` to the `.button` style, however, it will override all of the classes. The best way is to create a new class `.button-red` and use it.

Comment: @muecas `inherit` doesn't work.
@A.Lau I'm overwriting an app stylesheet which receives independent updates, and I don't want to touch their code

Comment: And if you use a mixin that writes the property only if a value is defined?

Comment: Yes i do @muecas

Comment: I think you should show the code that will override your styles so we can get. Better idea of  what you want to achieve. The problem is bot clear.

Comment: @muecas — That would inherit the backgroug-color [sic] from the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need for any additional setting in `search`.

```
.button {
  background-color: $red;
}
.button.search {
  /* no background-color setting would fallback to $red*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this so you can **extend** the style from **`.search`** and it will always fallback with whatever you define and incase you want to have new value for the .active class you can just write  `background-color: green;` **after** **`@extend .search;`**

```
.search {
  background-color: red;

&.active {
 @extend .search;
 // background-color: green;
 }
}
```

result will be like that

```
.search, .search.active {
   background-color: red;
}
```

and if you will do that

```
.search {
  background-color: red;

&.active {
 @extend .search;
  background-color: green;
 }
}
```

and result will be like that

```
.search, .search.active {
  background-color: red;
}
.search.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```